# What is the meaning of the vertical line in $\left.\left(\frac{2x^3}{3} - 4x^2 + 10x\right) \right|_1^3 = 12 - 20/3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

$$\left.\left(\frac{2x^3}{3} - 4x^2 + 10x\right) \right|_1^3 = 12 - 20/3$$

I guess my first question would be: What is the meaning of the vertical line in this equation?

I was under the impression it is meant to represent a range of $x$ values. However I'm not sure how both sides are equal, or how one would go about solving this.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff. I thank you with all my heart.

Comment: $ f(x) |_{x_0}^{x_1} = f(x_1) - f(x_0) $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typically used when solving definite integrals.

It means $f(3) - f(1)$, so:

$f(3) = (2/3)*27 - 4(9) + 10(3) = 12$, and

$f(1) = (2/3)*1 -4(1) + 10(1) = 20/3$

therefore $(12 - 20/3)$.

Note: be careful writing $2/3x^3$ because it could be incorrectly interpreted.

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x)\bigr|^b_a$$ is notation for $f(b)-f(a)$.